# Change Image Alternative text on select box change

Tags: forms, ajax

- Fields:

  - Image Field - field_image
  - Selectbox Field - field_custom_language
- Testcase: On selecting a different value from Selectbox, Alternative text of the image field should be changed.
- Issue: Alternative text is not changed on ajax call.

```
    function custom_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
      $form['field_custom_language']['widget']['#ajax'] = [
        'callback' => 'AltChange',
        'event' => 'change',
        'wrapper' => 'custom-image-wrapper',
        'progress' => [
          'type' => 'throbber',
          'message' => t('Loading...'),
        ],
      ];
    }

    function AltChange(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
      $form['field_image']['widget'][0]['#default_value']['alt'] = $form_state->getValue('field_custom_language');
      $form['field_image']['widget'][0] = ImageWidget::process($form['field_image']['widget'][0], $form_state, $form);
      return $form['field_image'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done using AJAX with php, image field doesn't expose the alt as field with value to change it.
But there is a way to do it by using [`custom Javascript in an AJAX callback`](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/ajax-forms#s-execute-custom-javascript-in-an-ajax-callback) like the following:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MODULENAME_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['field_custom_language']['widget']['#ajax'] = [
    'callback' => 'AltChange',
    'event'    => 'change',
    'wrapper'  => 'edit-field-image-wrapper',
    'progress' => [
      'type'    => 'throbber',
      'message' => t('Loading...'),
    ],
  ];
  // Add library.
  $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'MODULENAME/alter-alt-image';
}
```

and the callback function should be like:

```
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\InvokeCommand;
function AltChange(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  // Get the language value.
  $lang_code = $form_state->getValue('field_custom_language')[0]['value'];
  $response = new AjaxResponse();
  $response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand(NULL, 'AltChange', [$lang_code]));
  return $response;
}
```

and Then create the library:
***MODULENAME.libraries.yml***

```
alter-alt-image:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/script.js: {}
```

and your Js script:
***MODULENAME/js/script.js***

```
(function($) {
  // Argument passed from InvokeCommand.
  $.fn.AltChange = function(argument) {
    // Set alt value to the passed arguments.
    $('input#edit-field-image-0-alt').attr('value', argument);
  };
})(jQuery);
```